# showing image in email using the php image tracking trick

Tags: php

I am creating a newsletter system which tracks all types of information when emails are opened.

I have started with an image which looks like

```
<p><img src="http://xxx.com/newsletterInfo.php?newsletter=12&userid=234" width="314" height="20" alt="Cancel Newsletter Subscription"></p>
```

Then on the newsletterInfo.php file i am echo'ing the url to the image.

I take it this is not the way of doing this?

Can some please point to me where my problem is.

Thanks

**Update**

The sending of the email:

```
            $name = stripslashes($fetchquery["name"]);
            $email = stripslashes($fetchquery["email"]);

            $content = $_POST["maincontent"];
            $subject = $_POST["subject"];
            $message = "<html><head><title>".$subject."</title></head><body>";
            $message .= str_replace('{name}', $name, $content);
            $message .= '<p><img src="http://xxx.com/newsletterInfo.php?newsletter='.$id.'" width="314" height="20" alt="Cancel Newsletter Subscription"></p>';
            $message .= "</body></html>";

            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: Username <email@here.com>' . "\r\n";

            // Mail it
            mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

On the information page, i have done this:

```
if(isset($_GET["newsletter"])) {

    $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE newsletter SET opened=`opened` +1 WHERE id=:id");
    $query->execute(array(':id' => $_GET["newsletter"]));
    $query_num = $query->rowCount();

    if($query_num > 0){
        echo 'http://xxx.com/cancel.png';
    }
```

As you can see the email sends the newsletter using the mail() function and then where the image is i have put the url of a php file, within this file asks for the variable and if its set it then echos the image url and then inputs data into the database, all this works 100% because the database is being updated.

The problem that is having is the image is broken.

If you right click and go to the newsletterInfo.php the url shows.

I assume that this simply is not the way of doing this.

Comment: why this is not the way to do it ?  whats the problem ?

Comment: @vodich Sorry i forgot to actually say that the image is not showing. I dont understand what you mean by "Why this is not the way to do it?" Thanks

Comment: Paste some code so that we can see what is wrong in your code

Comment: You need to output some actual image data. Note however that these kinds of "web bugs" are often not displayed in E-Mail clients for reasons of privacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` attribute should point to an image. Your `src` points to the (dynamic) text file which contains URL, not the actual image. `newsletterInfo.php` should output an image, not its URL.

Possible solutions:

1. The easy way: make a redirection within `newsletterInfo.php`, like this:

   ```
   header('Location: url_to_the_image.jpg');
   ```

   (replace the file name with what you're currently echoing and remove that echo)
2. The hard way: open the image as a file, send proper headers and then echo the image. (not really a good idea)